# How do I remove the box around python code?

Tags: listings, code, python, box

I am using `\usepackage{pythonhighlight}` for python code and this creates a box around the code by default. Is there a way to remove the box?

```
\begin{python}
def f(x):
    return x
\end{python}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE .. Please post your code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like `pythonhighlight` has made it possible to add additional options to the `python` environment.

One option is to define a new `listings` type environment, and allow for style adjustments using the optional argument to the new environment, and add `frame=none` there. See `PythonA` below.

If you want to remove all frames, add `frame=none` to the new style, as with `PythonB` below.

A third option is to make a new style and use `\begin{lstlisting}[style=stylename]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{article}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\lstnewenvironment{PythonA}[1][]{\lstset{style=mypython, #1}}{}

\lstnewenvironment{PythonB}[1][]{\lstset{style=mypython, frame=none, #1}}{}

\lstdefinestyle{Py2}{
  style=mypython,
  frame=none
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{PythonA}[frame=none]
def f(x):
    return x
\end{PythonA}

\begin{PythonB}
def f(x):
    return x
\end{PythonB}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Py2]
def f(x):
    return x
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```